# Skip row in powershell while leaving the header

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file with 46000 rows and 8 columns.

I would need the number of rows to remain the same (46k); so when adding a new row I take the first one out (oldest - date based), leaving the header so I can allocate the new data to the right columns.

I can't use `For-Each` or any other loop because it takes ages.

When applying (example)...

```
Get-Content -Path $path | 
Select-Object -Skip 1 | 
Set-Content -Path $new-path
```

...it takes away the header as well.

I could of course re-import the csv assigning the header but that seems ugly. Is there any version of this code that takes away the first data-row but keeps the header standing?

Comment: As for this... "I could of course re-import the csv assigning the header but that seems ugly"... Why do you say this? It's a direct way of dealing with your use case. As for this "Is there any version of this code that takes away the first data-row but keeps the header standing?", sure, but may require more effort, so, why do that?

Comment: Quick and dirty is to just track the lines with a variable --> `$count = 0; gc $path | where {$count++ -ne 1}`

Answer (score 1):

Extending from my comment. As otherwise, you end up doing stuff sort of like this:

```
Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\book1.csv'
# Results
<#
"Site","Dept"
"Main","aaa,bbb,ccc"
"Branch1","ddd,eee,fff"
"Branch2","ggg,hhh,iii"
#>

Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\book1.csv' | 
Select-Object -Skip 2
# Results
<#
"Branch1","ddd,eee,fff"
"Branch2","ggg,hhh,iii"
#>

Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\book1.csv' | 
Select-Object -Skip 2 | 
ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Site, Dept
# Results
<#
Site    Dept       
----    ----       
Branch1 ddd,eee,fff
Branch2 ggg,hhh,iii
#>
```

As for using Import-Csv, you can use .Net ArrayList and do something like this:

```
([System.Collections.ArrayList]$BooksList = (Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\book1.csv'))
# Results
<#
Site    Dept       
----    ----       
Main    aaa,bbb,ccc
Branch1 ddd,eee,fff
Branch2 ggg,hhh,iii
#>

$BooksList.Remove($BooksList[0])
$BooksList
# Results
<#
Site    Dept       
----    ----       
Branch1 ddd,eee,fff
Branch2 ggg,hhh,iii
#>

$BooksList.Remove($BooksList[1])
$BooksList
# Results
<#
Site    Dept       
----    ----       
Branch1 ddd,eee,fff
#>
```

You can use the same approach to add record rows to the csv

```
Clear-Host
$BooksList = @()
([System.Collections.ArrayList]$BooksList = (Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\book1.csv'))
# Results
<#
Site    Dept       
----    ----       
Main    aaa,bbb,ccc
Branch1 ddd,eee,fff
Branch2 ggg,hhh,iii
#>

($AddToBooksList = [pscustomobject]@{
                      Site = 'Branch3'
                      Dept = 'jjj,kkk,lll'
                  }
)
# Results
<#
Site    Dept       
----    ----       
Branch3 jjj,kkk,lll
#>


$BooksList.Add($AddToBooksList)
# Results
<#
Site    Dept       
----    ----       
Main    aaa,bbb,ccc
Branch1 ddd,eee,fff
Branch2 ggg,hhh,iii
Branch3 jjj,kkk,lll
#>

$BooksList[3]
# Results
<#
Site    Dept       
----    ----       
Branch3 jjj,kkk,lll
#>
```

Comment: @sorcrow Please flag this as a anwser (The little checkmark under the votes)

Answer (score 0):

If the header doesnt change you could use the script you have and not skip a line and just rewrite the header.

Answer (score 0):

While using [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) and [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) is generally preferable, plain-text processing is required when performance matters.

The file sounds small enough to load into memory as a whole (twice), which speeds up processing:

```
# Read all lines into an array.
# -ReadCount 0 returns a single array, which is much faster than the
# default one-by-streaming of lines.
$lines = Get-Content -Path $path -ReadCount 0

# Determine the new row to add.
$newLine = '...'

# Write the modified array of lines back to the file.
# Using -Value to pass the array is much faster than using the pipeline.
# Adjust the encoding as needed
Set-Content $path -Encoding utf8 -Value (
  , $lines[0] + $lines[2..($lines.Count-1)] + $newLine
)
```